# Can't style new HTML5 input types in IE7 with type attribute selectors

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-7

It seems that even when using shivs you can't do something like `input[type="search"]` to style the new HTML5 input elements in IE7. You can see an example at http://jsfiddle.net/2tmAp/ (view it in IE7 modes of course).

Presumably IE7 is setting these elements to `type="text"` and even though the DOM itself is staying the same this still somehow prevents the styles from applying.

What would be the neatest way to fix this? Is there something we can do in Javascript to trick IE7 into applying the styles the same way as shivs work on elements?

Comment: add a class to all the matching elements and style using that class

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal that's definitely going to be my solution unless something better comes up. It's a bit of a bummer since I've used attribute selectors pretty liberally as I assumed they wouldn't be a problem anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shiv is just a way to force-create the new elements regardless if supported or not. but addressing the type and attributes it a different thing, as well as the selectors. the [fallbacks for the new "inputs" are the type "text"](http://www.coreservlets.com/html5-tutorial/input-types.html). this goes for the search, datepicker, and others (can't keep track of the new ones).

> There are two keys to understanding why the automatic fallback works consistently in all major browsers:
>
> - **The default type for input elements is "text"**.
> - All browsers ignore unknown attributes.
>
> The consequence of these two points is that if you say `<input type="foo" bar="baz"/>`, **all browsers will treat this identically to `<input type="text"/>`** (**unless "foo" is a recognized input** type or "bar" is a recognized attribute of the input element).

since `type="search"` is unknown to IE7, it falls back to `type="text"` and you can't pick it up in CSS as `type="search"` since it's now `type="text"`

to address your selector issue, you can try using [selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) which uses JS libraries' abilities to do selector matching cross-browser (even in non-supporting browsers using a some pseudo-selector matching script). i don't know if they pick-up shiv-created elements though.

or better, use the usual way to create a searchbox in HTML/JS as a fallback,

---

for an easy answer, i'd do what the other guy commented. Just create a class named "search" and apply this class name to all your search boxes. style them just the same as the one you used the selector with, just like:

```
input[type="search"],input.search{
    /*styles*/
}

<input type="search" class="search" />
```

Comment: I understand how the shiv works and I don't expect it to somehow implement form features. But for example, IE8 and FF don't support ``type="number"`` but will still match it with ``[type="number"]`` because that's what it is in the DOM.

Comment: that's IE8 and FF, not IE7. Have you tried Opera 9 or Chrome 4? because if it does work in the rest and not in IE7, then you can dismiss it as a limitation in IE7. like the answer says: *"all browsers will treat this identically to `<input type="text"/>` unless it's a recognized input"*

Comment: Well in one corner we have IE7 and Opera 8.5, and in the other Chrome 1, FF 3.0 and IE8. The way I've always read the part you are quoting is that it is to do with the actual widget that is displayed and says nothing about how styles are then matched against that widget.

Comment: how put this in simple terms.. the input `type="search"` you have falls back as `type="text"` for IE7 **because it doesn't recognize `type="search"`**. with that, it is styled as `type="text"`

Comment: I do understand that and it is in fact what I say in the second paragraph of my question, so there's no need to be condescending. My question was "what is the neatest way to fix this" and not "why is it happening". You seem to have hooked on to my mention of "tricking it like the shiv" and then gone off in another direction.

Comment: actually, i did edit my answer an hour ago. try it. and yes, i kinda got hooked to it.

Comment: The neatest solution for me actually ended up being to match against the ``name`` attribute instead. I just wanted to know if there was a novel solution since I opened a ticket about this issue on Selectivizr a couple hours previously https://github.com/keithclark/selectivizr/issues/33

Comment: don't wanna ruin your solution, Kyle, but using IDs (best) or class-names as Joseph suggested would greatly improve the selector performance. Attribute matching just isn't there yet - especially in older browsers --> do NOT use the name attribute for that!

Comment: i would try avoiding the use of IDs because of collisions (unless you're absolutely sure that the ID is used only by that element in the whole page)