# Getting new input types to work in old browsers

Tags: html, cross-browser

I'm trying to get the new input types working in IE9 IE8 IE7 but very unsuccessfully.

Does anybody know how to get that done?

I made it working for the new browsers using the datetime-polyfill,week-polyfill and webshim lib but i dont understand why webshim is not working for the IE9 8 7.I mean everything's good until I changed to IE9 and my range input became just a normal text field,same for number input.

I was thinking that the webshim will replace that lack of support with some slide widget but nothing. What am I missing please help?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Support of new input types in old browsers</title>
    <link href="inputs.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="jQuery/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="jQuery/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="datetime-polyfill.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="week-polyfill.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jQuery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="modernizr/modernizr.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="datetime-polyfill.js"></script>
    <script src="js-webshim/polyfiller.js"></script>
    <script>
        $.webshims.polyfill();
    </script>
    <script src="week-polyfill.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <article id="first">
            <strong>input type"range"</strong><input type="range" name="rangeInput" value="" min="0" max="100" step="10" />
        </article>
        <article>
            <strong>input type"number"</strong><input type="number" placeholder="0.5-10" min="0.5" max="10" step="0.5" />
        </article>
        <article>
            <strong>input type"email"</strong><input type="email" placeholder="email@where.domain"  />
        </article>
        <article>
            <strong>input type"color"</strong><input type="color" placeholder="your-default-color" value="#ff0000" />
        </article>
        <article>
            <strong>input type"date"</strong><input type="date" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" />
        </article>
        <article>
            <strong>input type"time"</strong><input type="time" placeholder="hh:mm AM/PM" />
        </article>
        <article>
            <strong>input type"datetime"</strong><input type="datetime" placeholder="date & time" />
        </article>
        <article>
            <strong>input type"month"</strong><input type="month" placeholder="e.g. Jan 2014" />
        </article>
        <article>
            <strong>input type"week"</strong><input type="week" placeholder="e.g. Week 38, 2014" />
        </article>
        <article>
            <strong>input type"search"</strong><input type="search" placeholder="search" />
        </article>
        <article>
            <strong>input type"tel"</strong><input type="tel" placeholder="+xxx(xxx)xxxxxx" pattern="[\+]\d{3}[\(]\d{3}[\)]\d{6}" />
        </article>
        <article>
            <strong>input type"url"</strong><input type="url" placeholder="a valid url(http://)" />
        </article>
        <article id="last">
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </article>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you opened the browser console and looked wether there are messages/errors?

Comment: yes there are 2 errors first is:IE browser modes are busted in IE10+. Make sure to run IE in edge mode (X-UA-Compatible). Please test your HTML/CSS/JS with a real IE version or at least IETester or similar tools, and second is: [type="color"] used without adding it to the types config.

Comment: Ok, than this should be the answer. Test in real IE and it will work.

Comment: Thanks that was really my answer.I tried it on IETester and its working on IE8 and IE9,but still nothing on IE7.Again thank u  i will be still looking for a solution on IE7...

Comment: IE7 is not supported by webshim 1.12+ anymore. If you want to support IE7 you can use version 1.11.6 (https://github.com/aFarkas/webshim/archive/1.11.6.zip). But why? Noone is using this browser anymore.

Answer (score 4):

HTML5 Inputs types are not supported in older browsers Like `IE7-IE8` and automatically fall back to `input type="text"` which is supported in these browsers.

A relevant question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644600/cant-style-new-html5-input-types-in-ie7-with-type-attribute-selectors).

If you want to support these validations you have to do this with JavaScript validations for old browsers.

You can try [h5Validate - HTML5 Form Validation for jQuery](http://ericleads.com/h5validate/) which is supported in older browsers as well. Tested on 13 different browsers, `IE6-IE9`, `FireFox`, `Chrome`, `iPhone`, and `Android`.

Another option is to use [Modernizr](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills).

good luck!